# Wrong reading from Google Place Android API

Tags: android

i have developed an application that interacts with google places api to search for cafe in the neighborhood of a user. for the purpose of my application i want to have the radius set to a very small value.. may be 20 to 50 meters. currently my app is working but its not working the way it should.
In my app, i have set the radius to 350 meters. so practically it should return me the list of cafe that fall in the radius of 350m. however my app still shows starbucks in this result set even if starbucks is 650m (road distance) and 500m (straight distance). I would like to know what should be done to get the correct results.
Currently i am using GPS for this. will a combination of gps and network service provide me a better reading?

```
public PlacesList search(double latitude, double longitude, double radius, String types)
throws Exception {

    this._latitude = latitude;
    this._longitude = longitude;
    this._radius = radius;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this question is not related to Android, but to the Google Places API.

are you using place search or text search? both of them have comments regarding location biasing

**text search:**

"You may bias results to a specified circle by passing a location and a radius parameter. This will instruct the Place service to prefer showing results within that circle; results outside of the defined area may still be displayed."

**place search:**

"distance. This option sorts results in ascending order by their distance from the specified location. Ranking results by distance will set a fixed search radius of 50km. One or more of keyword, name, or types is required."

Comment: Hi Gal, thanks again for replying on my post. I am using text search. I am aware that there are two kinds of searches.. One that returns results based on prominence and the other based on distance. I am looking forward to prominence because i want to make use of radius parameter in places search. i am referring to google places api for Android. I am developing an android app.. now based on this info, can you please tell me what can be the reason for getting such a huge error value in  gps reading?

Comment: "You may bias results to a specified circle by passing a location and a radius parameter. This will instruct the Place service to prefer showing results within that circle; results outside of the defined area may still be displayed." - this is from the Places API documentation

Comment: ok.. then this is what is happening. even though i am restricting places api to return the places that fall in 350m radius, it is still showing me the place that is more than 500m away. SO IS THERE NO WAY TO CORRECT THIS? Also do you know while searching for places in a given radius, Google does this based on straight distance or it takes road networks into consideration or it just returns the places that fall into that circle? Please answer both the questions if you can..

Comment: this is the expected behavior of the Google Places API and it is well documented, you can filter the results yourself before they're displayed to the user. You are providing 'radius' to the API so it probably doesn't care about road networks. I fully answered your question, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: ok, i have accepted the answer.. but still my main question is not answered.. i would appreciate if you answer that.. when my radius is set to 350m, then why google places api is returning a place that is 600m from my place? it is well beyond the radius.. can u help me with that??

Comment: this is how Google Places API works and it is well documented. if you don't like this behavior you have two options: a) filter the results yourself, b) use another geo-location API